# Page design changed when html moved to aspx page

Tags: css, asp.net, runatserver

I am facing a strange issue. I have a html page whose design is perfect but when I am copying the same to aspx then design got distorted. Now, when I removed

```
<form id="form1" runat="server"> and <head runat="server">
```

attribute then design got corrected.

I am not sure why this has happened and how can I fix that because I don't think it's a good idea to remove form tag from aspx page

Comment: runat="server" has nothing to do with your page design. The control you want to make available in your backend .cs file (server side) should have this attribute.

Comment: @AshadShanto So, I can remove both these tags from design page and keep them in html or asp control which ever I want to access from backend?

Comment: Can you share your complete code? That might make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue.

Some of my CSS was referring to ID, when I changed it to class it started working as per my expectation.

It is an important note for all ASP.NET webform developers: "Do styling with class only"

```
Ex: #Myclass
{
 height:10px;
}

<div id="divId" class="MyClass"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your .css file(s) of your application where aspx resides. There must be styles defined for form element.
Better way to check style relaed issues is to use browser's developer tools.

Comment: I am checking the same from web insepctor, every single line of html code is same except form and head runat tag

Comment: You need to check all those CSS files which has been included in aspx page, of course if any. Checking html may not help if you referencing external css.